# Active or inactive users

Tags: python-3.x, django, authentication, bootstrap-4, user-controls

I'm trying to design a django application where users' accounts can only be activated after making payments...Inactive users are denied all the web functionalities until the make payments. How can I go about this?

Comment: Can you show your current testing code

Answer (score 0):

you can make custom permission, and apply it on any function you want

please take a look for `decorators`

for example:

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import permission_required

@permission_required('product.change_name')
def admin_view(request):
    """Raise permission denied exception or redirect user"""
```

you can create your own `decorators` and use it

Comment: Thanks Hanshem, your idea saved me a great deal